# How to repeat rows and add increment numbers at the end?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I need the formula to duplicate specific rows (the rows contain name data) a number of times and add incrementing numbers in the end.

It should look something like this:

[image: problem]

I found a way to dublicale the rows, using this formula

```
=if(Rows(E$2:E2) >$B$10*$B$11;""; index(A$2:A$7; mod(Rows(E$2:E2)-1;$B$13)+1))
```

Now I need to add numbers in the end. I am wondering if it is possible to do it in one formula, or do I need to create a separate column and concatenate it together.

Comment: do you still seek the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue can be solved using one Helper Column:**

*Since most of Excel commands are working with Google Spreadsheet, therefore this method can be applied on your Workbook also.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Fill Cell `L9`, `L10` & `L12` with `6`, `2`, `6`.
- Enter the Formula you have used to get name list in Cell `N2`.

  ```
  =IF(ROWS(N$2:N2) >$L$9*$L$10,"", INDEX(K$2:K$8, MOD(ROWS(N$2:N2)-1,$L$12)+1))
  ```
- Now, enter this Formula in Cell `O2` to get **Helper Values** (are simply Count of 
  occurrence) and fill it down.

`=Countif($N$2:$N2,N2)`

- **Copy** Range `O2:O13`, using **Paste Special** pick **Values** & finish with **Ok,** on same Range `O2:O13`.
- Re-write the Formula in Cell `N2` with this one.

  ```
  =IF(ROWS(N$2:N2) >$L$9*$L$10,"", INDEX(K$2:K$8, MOD(ROWS(N$2:N2)-1,$L$12)+1))&" "&O2
  ```

**N.B.**

- Correction with Formula is `&" "&O2` at the end.
- Re-writing Range `O2:O13` is needed (using Copy & Paste as Value) to avoid the **Circular reference** for the new version of the Formula finished with `&" "&O2`.
- **Helper Column** is `Col O`
- You may adjust cell references as needed.